# django admin gives warning "Field 'X' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: django, django-admin, autofield

I have created two models out of an existing legacy DB , one for articles and one for tags that one can associate with articles:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'articles'
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    article=models.ForeignKey(Article)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'article_tags'
```

I want to enable adding tags for an article from the admin interface, so my `admin.py` file looks like this:

```
from models import Article,Tag
from django.contrib import admin
class TagInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Tag


class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [TagInline]

admin.site.register(Article,ArticleAdmin)
```

The interface looks fine, but when I try to save, I get:
`Warning at /admin/webserver/article/382/
Field 'tag_id' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: why are you using `AutoFields` for fields `model_id`, they are automatically created and set as primary keys by django.

Comment: @dcrodjer - I am using a legacy DB

Comment: Have you made any model/database table changes (after syncing the db) and not synced them? Look [here](http://manydemons.com/blog/2010/10/field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value-django-python/)

Comment: @dcrodjer - so does this means it's a django bug? seems odd

Comment: why django bug you say!! I am asking if you reset the tables and syncd databases

Comment: @dcrodjer - I have synced the db. But haven't reset the tables; I am not sure I understand why is that a solution - What will reseting my tables, and reinserting all the data accomplish? will the resulting db be different in any way? In any case, I want to understand the cause of the problem and not just try to hack at it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that in the DB, `tag_id` wasn't set as an autoincrement field.

Answer (score 5):

This can also happen if you have a disused field in your database that doesn't allow NULL.

Answer (score 1):

What solved this issue in my case was disabling `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` SQL mode which was enabled by default.

Comment: Yes me too I disabled this
 # 'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",